# Creating a .ics file type " Absence"

Tags: java, eclipse, icalendar

Why when i create a new file .ics with X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS = OOF ( out of office ), the event received is in status "Busy" ?

I use ical4j jar , java

Comment: no one have a solution to my problem ?

Comment: The solution is to use Exchange server 2010. The issue appears when I use Exchange server 2007.